# Why method that calls another one which throws RuntimeException needs return statement?

Tags: java, exception

Why unreachable statement is not identified by javac ?

```
public int directThrow(){
     throw new RuntimeException();
    //Compiles fine
}

public int indirectThrow(){
    directThrow();
    // Missing Return Statement error
}
```

Comment: What if you override directThrow in a subclass? Javac only pays attention to the method signature when you're calling it from another method, not the body. And java doesn't even have a way to express that a method never returns normally.

Comment: I guess this would need a deep scan. if you can imagine... this could lead to extremly long compilation times, as the hirarchy (call stack) can be a very deep and long "thing".

Comment: @Sunchezz you can do it with a special return type for a method. In Kotlin , the return type `Nothing` Indicates this. The compiler checks that this is true for a method (either always throws or is an infinite loop)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt with return type `Nothing`, i can do what in java? Make the Compiler do a deep scan for Exception throwing?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt regarding overriding `public final int directThrow(){..}`  fails to compile also.

Comment: Your question does not mention any `final`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler simply isn't designed to analyse your code *that* deeply.

For `directThrow`, the compiler looks at it and says, "I see you have a throw statement, so the method will terminate abruptly here, no need for a return statement then!"

For `indirectThrow`, the compiler looks at it and says, "I only see a method call. Hey programmer! You need a return statement here!"

The compiler doesn't look at what `directThrow` actually does. I think this is quite reasonable, because the benefit of analysing what every method you call does is really small, compared to the cost of increased compilation time. Think about what the compiler needs to check to make sure that `directThrow` will always throw an exception. The most important thing being, is it overridden by anything? Can you even check that? Can you even make sure that no class in the future will subclass your class and override that method (give your class and `directThrow` are both non-`final`)?

If you have some complicated exception-throwing logic that you want to extract into a method, you can extract it into a method that returns the `Exception`:

```
private Exception someComplicatedLogicThatGivesAnException() { ... }

public void foo() {
    if (...) {
        throw someComplicatedLogicThatGivesAnException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Counter question: What *if* `directThrow()` was somehow altered that it doesn't throw an exception? How should the code then handle that?

To illustrate this problem, here's an example:

```
class Foo {
    int throwSomething() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    int throwSomething() {
        return 1; // hahaaa, we don't throw but return normally
    }
}
```

See? The subclass overrides the base method, and returns something, how should the code now handle that:

```
int indirectThrowing(Foo foo) {
    foo.throwSomething();
}
```

If we pass `new Foo()` it will throw as expected, but if we pass `new Bar()` it will just return `1`. And thus it will not fail.

To overcome this problem, you **must** write a return statement. Or if you want to reuse what you already have, you can also write:

```
return directThrow();
```

Because `directThrow()` has a return type `int`, and thus you just pass the argument upwards.

Note, some languages like Kotlin handle this with a `Nothing` (sometimes called also `Never`) return type. To indicate to the compiler that a method can never return normally.